# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for all CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I have created Application with yeoman In local machine it is working fine. Once you deploy in server it is show `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.

[image]

I am adding all dependence with bower.I am doing anything wrong please help.
If you need any other information let me know.

**EDIT**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Open URL manually. I guess server is returning error page

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: @AdnanUmer server is send me the index page and error is showing on <!doctype html>

Comment: showme ur app.js code @ lines between 5 to 15

Comment: @SrinivasPai You say you're using a CDN but you're obviously not - you're obviously using local files. Are you sure your webserver has direct access to the files and they're located in the place you're referring to?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes I added all dependence with bower it works in local but from webserver i am getting index page and error is showing on <!doctype html>

Comment: It could be one of the following, but we don't know more than that: 1): Rewrite issue (pass everything through index.php - this should ONLY be done if the file doesn't already exist, since we don't know your webserver or your config (htaccess etc) we can't say anything about it). 2): Permission issues (your files might be unreadable by the www-user on your server). 3): Files not existing issues (you think you've uploaded the files somewhere, but you've put them in the wrong directory hence you're getting a 404 / automatic rewrite).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Okay I will check with these options But it is not definitely 3rd options coz it is giving me 200. Still I will check other 2 options.

Comment: could you add some code please ? show us your index

Comment: @SrinivasPai Your server can be set up to modify the 404 NOT FOUND into a 200 OK header to hide the fact that a file doesn't exist. This is usually done for security reasons (as people can't use a script that detects 404's to just search for places like `/wp-admin/index.php`, `/admin/index.php` etc)

Comment: I Have edited my question added my index code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ok I will check that option as well. Thnaks

Comment: don't post pictures of code. copy it and paste it here

Comment: Now we can see your code (although as a screenshot) but no directory structure - do you have a `bower_components` directory in the root of your server (same place as your main index file)? Do you run the server in a sub folder (eg. `http://www.domain.com/test/subsite/mysite/bower_component`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a result of one or all of those files not existing. I often see this issue when I use relative paths in script src attributes.

Try prepending a '/' to all of your asset tags. I.e.

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Also, you may want to include a base tag in the head block:

```
<base href="/">
```